# Leaflet get bounds of whole map

Tags: leaflet, mapping

My map is a rectangle, divided in smaller `x-y-z` images.

`map.getBounds()` returns the bounds of the visible map. I want to compute the bounds of the whole map, from corner to corner, regardless of the visible section

How can I compute these bounds?

EDIT:
the map is created with this code. It's a video game map not a world map that's why the crs

```
    let map = L.map('map', {
        crs: L.CRS.EPSG4326,
        zoomControl: false,
    }).setView([0, 0], 7);
    L.tileLayer.customUrlLayer('', {
        maxNativeZoom: 7,
        minNativeZoom: 7,
        tileSize: 1024,
    }).addTo(map);
```

URL:

```
    L.TileLayer.CustomUrlLayer = L.TileLayer.extend({
        getTileUrl: function(coords) {
            return `https://img.example.com/${coords.z}/${coords.x}/${coords.y}`
        }
    });
```

ASCII view (many images):

```
A                               B
---------------------------------
|        ||        |...|        |
|  1024  ||  1024  |...|  1024  |
|        ||        |...|        |
---------------------------------
             ...
---------------------------------
|        ||        |...|        |
|  1024  ||  1024  |...|  1024  |
|        ||        |...|        |
---------------------------------
C                               D
```

Comment: Please edit you question and add more of relevant code (map, layers), so it won't be necessary to ask you a bunch of questions.

Comment: `myLayer.getBounds()` should return the bounds for a layer, so loop over the layers  (except any background layer, which will probably have a bounds of the whole earth) that constitute your map? Have you tried that?

Comment: @Spacedman Tile layer does not have `.getBounds()` method.

Comment: Check the Capabilities document of your layer and search for the ```<ows:WGS84BoundingBox>``` property (if it's a wmts)

Comment: We need to know a bit more about the type of layers in your map, and/or the leaflet code used to create it.

Comment: @Spacedman edited

Comment: @BerndLoigge edited

Comment: @TomazicM no. How do you compute that number? Also I see I can zoom in/out and `map.getZoom()` returns a different number, but the images are always the same

Comment: For computing the number see https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames. So what is then your bounding box in terms of tile numbers: `[minTileNoX, minTileNoY, maxTileNoX, maxTileNoY]`?

Comment: @TomazicM [-10,-9,7,8]

Comment: Sorry, mistake in my comment about total number of tiles. I overlooked that tile size is 1024x1024, so total number of tiles at zoom 7 is 32x32.

Comment: @TomazicM the problem is that I can zoom in and out and the bounds change. I do not know how to know the bounds for any zoom. For only one zoom value I can know it

Comment: If I understand you correctly then, you want bounds of visible tiles/map?

Comment: @TomazicM no, of the whole map: visible + invisible. I want to place popups on precise parts of the map and I need to know xy from the top-left of the map for any zoom. I can do this on one zoom but not on all zooms. The problem is when the zoom changes latlngs change between two points thus I must recompute everything. If I knew the bounds I could do it

Comment: @TomazicM I'm looking for a way to know any two of the 4 corners (ABCD in ASCII above) of the full map regardless of zoom and visible view of the map